# Como puxar todas as linhas do banco em php mas mostrando uma vez só o valor de uma coluna específica de consulta?

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoal estou com um problema, tenho uma tela em PHP que mostra tudo de uma consulta do banco.

Até ai tudo ok, porém preciso mostrar todas as informações sem replicar a coluna pedidos.

Seguem os prints.

O primeiro é que eu trago hoje:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O segundo é o que preciso fazer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando um `while` no PHP puxando de um banco de dados MySQL.

Segue o código:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 
                            a.num_pedido,
                            nota_fiscal,
                            lote_serial,
                            produto,
                            qtd_disp-pedido qtd_disp,
                            lote,
                            unid_medida,
                            pedido,
                            a.status,
                            cnpj,
                            a.nome_cli,
                            a.endereco,
                            a.numero,
                            a.bairro,
                            a.cep_cli,
                            a.cidade,
                            cod_id,
                            data 
                            from
                            sistemas_ag.clientes_ag a left join
                        sistemas_ag.agendamento_ag b on a.num_pedido = b.num_pedido
                        where cnpj = '".$cnpj."' 
                        and (a.num_pedido like '%$busca%'
                        or nota_fiscal like '%$busca%'
                        or produto like '%$busca%'
                        or lote_serial like '%$busca%')
                        order by length(a.num_pedido), a.num_pedido asc")or die("erro no select verifica pedido");
```

Comment: rapaz eu não entendi o que você precisa

Comment: preciso mesclar as informações da primeira coluna mostrando só uma vez mais sem ocultar a outras. preciso de alguma coisa que verifique se o valor é repetido se for mostra uma vez

Comment: o problema de ocultar que no caso, são id's diferentes, como você trataria isso ? se possivel coloque a query que você usou para gera esse grid

Comment: É só usar a comando `DISTINCT` do mysql, que só retornará uma vez um pedido.

Comment: Não é na query que você vai alterar isso. Vai ter que alterar é na programação de exibição desses dados na tela. Cadê o código?

Comment: vese um `GROUP BY a.num_pedido` resolve, pelo menos a parte dos registros duplicados acho que vai resolver. Mas pode ser que acabe "faltando" algumas linhas.

Answer (score 2):

O que vc precisa é utilizar o atributo "rowspan" na tag td do html (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp).

Fiz um exemplo de uso utilizando o laço de repetição foreach. Recomendo inclusive que utilize foreach ao invés de while para exposição de dados. Claro que existem exceções.

```
<?php
$pk = "id";
$products = [
    [$pk => 1,"name" => "mouse"],
    [$pk => 1,"name" => "mouse"],
    [$pk => 2,"name" => "keyboard"],
    [$pk => 2,"name" => "keyboard"],
    [$pk => 2,"name" => "keyboard"],
    [$pk => 3,"name" => "notebook"],
    [$pk => 3,"name" => "notebook"],
    [$pk => 4,"name" => "desktop"],
];
array_push($products, [$pk => ""]);
?>

<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    $repeats = [];
    foreach($products as $i => $product):
        if($i === 0):
            array_push($repeats, $product);
        elseif($product[$pk] !== $products[$i-1][$pk]):
            foreach($repeats as $iRepeat => $repeat):
    ?>
        <tr>
        <?php if($iRepeat === 0): ?>
            <td rowspan="<?= count($repeats) ?>"><?= $repeat[$pk] ?></td>
        <?php endif ?>
            <td><?= $repeat["name"] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
            endforeach;
            $repeats = [];
            array_push($repeats, $product);
        else:
            array_push($repeats, $product);
        endif;
    endforeach;
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o "DISTINCT" no seu select, já resolveria o problema dos dados da coluna vindo repetidos. Com o "DISTINCT", os dados daquela coluna (com o mesmo valor) só são retornados uma vez naquela consulta.

```html
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT 
                            a.num_pedido,
                            nota_fiscal,
                            lote_serial,
                            produto,
                            qtd_disp-pedido qtd_disp,
                            lote,
                            unid_medida,
                            pedido,
                            a.status,
                            cnpj,
                            a.nome_cli,
                            a.endereco,
                            a.numero,
                            a.bairro,
                            a.cep_cli,
                            a.cidade,
                            cod_id,
                            data 
                            from
                            sistemas_ag.clientes_ag a left join
                        sistemas_ag.agendamento_ag b on a.num_pedido = b.num_pedido
                        where cnpj = '".$cnpj."' 
                        and (a.num_pedido like '%$busca%'
                        or nota_fiscal like '%$busca%'
                        or produto like '%$busca%'
                        or lote_serial like '%$busca%')
                        order by length(a.num_pedido), a.num_pedido asc")or die("erro no select verifica pedido");
```